# issue with EGOTableViewPullRefresh - not changing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use **EGOTableViewPullRefresh** in my project but i'm having a problem, the "**release to refresh**" not showing and the arrow not animating when scrolling.

[image: EGOTableViewPullRefresh issue, release to refresh not showing]

I was using this tutorial 
[How to EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/how-to-egotableviewpullrefresh/)
but i had a small difference , my project doesn't use storyboards and it has a normal viewController with a tableView inside it, this tableview linked to another tableViewController.

I couldn't write all what i did, so I have uploaded a simple project that view my problem.

Here is the project [View in Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByHo3vkJ5W7wZVlsX1RPdUxpelE/edit?usp=sharing).

I think the problem is caused from tableView datasource and delegate, but I don't know how to solve it, any ideas ??

Thanks

Comment: Checking it out now...

Comment: Why aren't you making the EGO view in your table view controller?

Comment: @Undo this example is a part of another huge project, where I was trying to include many tableViews in one viewController, and these views has a prototype, dataSource and delegate in another files... exactly like viewContainer.. but I'm trying to support IOS 4.3, so I need to make the EGO view in the table View not in the table view controller, I hope there is any way to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with your UITableView. `ViewController` has to be the delegate of the UITableView in order to receive this events:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Put this line on your `viewDidLoad` and try:

```
self.newsView.delegate = self;
```

Or if you prefer use the ViewController XIB change the delegate property of the UITableView to the File's Owner.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, but it helped me too much, thanks a lot